# Is C14 dating reliable for antique authentication?

Tags: radioactivity

Some people say, sometimes, faked antiques can cheat [$\rm C^{14}$ dating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiocarbon_dating).

Which kind of technologies do they use?

Answer (score 2):

They need the organic materials they use to date from prior to the date they claim.  I could fabricate a wooden chair and claim it was from $1800$.  I would need to find wood that was older than $1800$.  Depending on the sophistication of the challenge, I might have to find all the organic elements for paint and glue from that era as well.  That would be harder, but as less material is used it is harder to date by $C^{14}$.  Another approach would be to buy purified $C^{12}$, make paints and glues, and mix them with normal modern stuff.  That would probably be economically unfeasible.